# How to create IF statement in jQuery / Ajax get in PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

How can add IF statement inside jQuery ?

I have these **2(two)** rows of data in database that have different status.

[image]

And my **index.php** is my main file to display the data.

**index.php**

```
$.get("test.php", {"test": "test"})
.done(function (data) {  
    var displayString = ""; 
    $.each(JSON.parse(data), function (key, value) {
         displayString +=
            "<tr>" + 
                "<td>" +  
                    '<a class="btn btn-xs btn-default btn-flat" target="_blank" href="view.php?param='+ value['APPLICATION_STATUS'] +' ">' +
                        '<i class="fa fa-eye"></i> ' +
                    '</a>' +  
                "</td>" + 
                displayString += "<td>" +  
                            if (value['APPLICATION_STATUS'] == 'APPROVED'){

                            } 
                            else { 

                                + '<a class="btn btn-xs btn-warning btn-flat" target="_blank" href="edit.php?param='+ value['APPLICATION_STATUS'] +' ">' +
                                    '<i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> ' +
                                '</a>' + 

                            }  
       displayString += "</td>" + 
            "</tr>";
    }); 
    $('#fTableBody').css("display", "none");
    $("#tableBody").html(displayString);
    $("#table-view").dataTable({
    dom: 'Blfrtip',
    scrollX: true, 
    buttons: [
    'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
    ],
    "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]]
    });
});
```

And I fetch data from **test.php** using jQuery .get and here's what I have so far.

**test.php**

```
<?php
    require 'connection.php';
    $query = "SELECT APPLICATION_STATUS FROM TABLE"; 
    $result = oci_parse($conn, $query);
    oci_execute($result);
    $arr = array();
    while ($row = oci_fetch_array($result)){
        $arr[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

My question is, how can I add if statement inside the .each json parse ?

I want to **disable/hide edit.php button** when 'application_status' is '**APPROVED**'.

Appreciate if someone can help. Thanks

Comment: Assuming `value['APPLICATION_STATUS']` returns the correct value, does `if(value['APPLICATION_STATUS'] == 'APPROVED'){}` not work for you?

Comment: @CarlBinalla does not work for me. it says unexpected if token .

Comment: And it throw error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Comment: Since you have tried something, can you add it?

Comment: @CarlBinalla coding updated above. but stil the same error :  Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Comment: The problem is not with the `if()`, but with how you concatenate the string to `displayString ` in the `else{}` clause

Comment: @CarlBinalla So you can help me to fix the code above instead ?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help your problem :

```
<script>
 $.get("test.php", {
      "test": "test"
 }).done(function(data) {
      var displayString = "";
      $.each(JSON.parse(data), function(key, value) {
           displayString +=
                "<tr>" +
                "<td>" +
                '<a class="btn btn-xs btn-default btn-flat" target="_blank" href="view.php?param=' + value['APPLICATION_STATUS'] + ' ">' +
                '<i class="fa fa-eye"></i> ' +
                '</a>' +
                "</td>";
           displayString += "<td>";
           // make a condition
           if (value['APPLICATION_STATUS'] == 'APPROVED') {
                displayString += 'hide button';
           } else {
                displayString += '<a class="btn btn-xs btn-warning btn-flat" target="_blank" href="edit.php?param=' + value['APPLICATION_STATUS'] + ' ">' + '<i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>' + '</a>';
           }
           displayString += "</td>";
           displayString += "</tr>";
      });
      $('#fTableBody').css("display", "none");
      $("#tableBody").html(displayString);
      $("#table-view").dataTable({
           dom: 'Blfrtip',
           scrollX: true,
           buttons: [
                'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
           ],
           "lengthMenu": [
                [10, 25, 50, -1],
                [10, 25, 50, "All"]
           ]
      });
 });
```

Comment: Nope. Error : check.php:460 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Comment: Its okay. I already found the simplest answer. I create if statement first, then on if block i paste the whole displayString. that solve my problem. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is the correct answer or not but it solved my problem.

**index.php**

```
$.get("test.php", {"test": "test"})
    .done(function (data) {  
        var displayString = ""; 
        $.each(JSON.parse(data), function (key, value) {
            if(value['APPLICATION_STATUS'] == 'APPROVED')
        {
            displayString +=
            "<tr>" +  
                "<td>" +  
                    '<a class="btn btn-xs btn-default btn-flat" target="_blank" href="view.php?param='+ value['APPLICATION_STATUS'] +' ">' +
                        '<i class="fa fa-eye"></i> ' +
                    '</a>' +  
                "</td>" +   
            "</tr>";
        }
        else
        {
            displayString +=
            "<tr>" +  
                "<td>" +  
                    '<a class="btn btn-xs btn-default btn-flat" target="_blank" href="view.php?param='+ value['APPLICATION_STATUS'] +' ">' +
                        '<i class="fa fa-eye"></i> ' +
                    '</a>' +  
                "</td>" + 
                "<td>" +  
                    '<a class="btn btn-xs btn-warning btn-flat" target="_blank" href="edit.php?param='+ value['APPLICATION_STATUS'] +' ">' +
                        '<i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> ' +
                    '</a>' + 
                "</td>" +  
            "</tr>";
        }

        }); 
        $('#fTableBody').css("display", "none");
        $("#tableBody").html(displayString);
        $("#table-view").dataTable({
        dom: 'Blfrtip',
        scrollX: true, 
        buttons: [
        'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ],
        "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]]
        });
    });
```

Thanks.